# Aggregation in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data something like this:

```
declare @table table
(
    CUSTNO varchar(35),
    RELATIONNO int,
    Sales numeric(5,2), 
    RelationDate dateTIME
)

insert into @table

select 'B1024818',  120,    189.26, '2013-10-27' union all
select 'B1024818',  120,    131.76, '2016-10-28' union all
select 'C0002227',  124,    877.16, '2012-08-26' union all
select 'C0002227',  124,    802.65, '2015-06-15'
```

I am trying to get a result like

```
CUSTNO     RELATIONNO     Sales    Till Last Relation Year
----------------------------------------------------------
B1024818        120       321.02         2016
C0002227        124      1679.81         2015
```

Here sales is added for each customer from 1st Relation date to Last Relation date

In a Till Last Relation Year COLUMN it contain highest year for each customer

I am not sure whether it is possible in SQL.

Please share your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT custno, RELATIONNO, sum(Sales), MAX(year(RelationDate ))
FROM @table
GROUP BY custno, RELATIONNO
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT CUSTNO, RELATIONNO, SUM(Sales) AS Sales, MAX(YEAR(RelationDate))
FROM @table
GROUP BY CUSTNO, RELATIONNO;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/QNUD49542)**

Answer (score 1):

you can use below query -

```
select CUSTNO ,RELATIONNO ,SUM(Sales)  as Sales , max(Year(RelationDate )) [Till Last Relation Year]
from  @table
group by CUSTNO ,RELATIONNO
```